# How to add same set of tasks (as child) to multiple user stories in tfs?

Tags: tfs

Suppose i have some set of tasks say:-

> 1. Analysing Code.
> 2. Coding.
> 3. Exception Handling.
> 4. View Integration
> 5. Deployment.
> 6. Bug Fixing.

How do i bulk create the same set of tasks under multiple user stories as its respective child objects?

Eg:- say i have

> 45678,45679,45670,45671,45672 as my user stories.
>   If i manually create the 6 listed tasks to the 1st user story, then how can i bulk create the same set of tasks to all other user stories as child objects?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automation out of the box for this.

You can use excel to copy/paste the tasks as children of PBI's. There are also some third party tools out there that can do what you want. I built the TFS Event Handler in 2008 for an organization but have not had much call for it since.

http://nakedalm.com/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010/

The reason I don't get much call for this sort of thing is that if you need it, then you are doing something wrong. Your list above is something that would make a lot more sense on a definition of done than a task list. If this was the DOD then the tasks should be the development teams plan to get them done...

Comment: Thanks for your input @MrHinsh. Microsoft excel 2013 has a built in tfs plugin which helps you publish bulk data to tfs. But the configuration alone takes a lot of time to accurately insert the data. I was hoping if there was an option similar to "Relate" in tfs. Instead of just relating a set of tasks to multiple user stories, create multiple instances of the same tasks in multiple User Stories.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that and I hope they never implement it as those sort of features produce dysfunctional behavior in teams.

Comment: Agreed . Will have to manually enter then. Excel will help for the moment.